# htaccess conflict on shared hosting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

The ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE comes randomly on www.domain.com/ci_project

I have a shared hosting with multiple domain hosted on it. In the root folder of my hosting exists a .htaccess file. The code is as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And inside a folder there is a codeigniter site say ci_project. The htaccess is as follows

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

If I comment the htaccess file of the ci_project, www.domain.com/ci_project works fine without the random error But I need the htaccess file as it removes index.php from the url

Can anyone please tell how the issue can be resolved..

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the pages in a browser other than Chrome.

If the issue (random error) is not appearing in other browsers then clear the browser cache of Chrome and then open the pages. This random error should disappear.

Comment: issue appears in all browsers